# Mutt skip compose menu

Tags: linux, cron, command, command-line-interface, mutt

Are there any command line options/flags/ways to compose a message with mutt and skip the interface entirely? For example, when I run something like

```
mutt -i ~/output.txt -s 'Test results' name@domain.com
```

I don't want 3 editor windows and a compose menu (where I have to enter 'y' to send) to come up that I have to manually get through before sending the message.  This is to be run in a cron-job so it should be fully automated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to work with my version of mutt, but I don't know if the feature is universally available:

```
echo "" | mutt -s "my subject" -i <(echo bla) -a file.txt -- name@domain.com
```

Comment: worked for me! i supposed thats a general solution for any commands with an interface?